# Nginx can't load image correctly

Tags: image, nginx

When i try to load http://example.net/upload/avatar/large/5.png
it displayed default.png appearance but named 5.png. 
However,I looked picture by Filezilla ,everything is okay.
Please help me ;C

nginx.conf:

```html
`user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections 768;
 # multi_accept on;
}


http {

 ##
 # Basic Settings
 ##

 sendfile off;
 tcp_nopush on;
 tcp_nodelay on;
 keepalive_timeout 2;
 types_hash_max_size 2048;
 client_max_body_size 100m;
 # server_tokens off;

 # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
 # server_name_in_redirect off;

 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 default_type application/octet-stream;

 ##
 # Logging Settings
 ##

 access_log off;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

 ##
 # Gzip Settings
 ##

 gzip on;
 gzip_disable "msie6";

 # gzip_vary on;
 # gzip_proxied any;
 # gzip_comp_level 6;
 # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
 # gzip_http_version 1.1;
 # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

 ##
 # nginx-naxsi config
 ##
 # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
 ##

 #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

 ##
 # nginx-passenger config
 ##
 # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
 ##
 
 #passenger_root /usr;
 #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

 ##
 # Virtual Host Configs
 ##

 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}



#mail {
# # See sample authentication script at:
# # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
# # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
# # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
# # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
# server {
#  listen     localhost:110;
#  protocol   pop3;
#  proxy      on;
# }
# 
# server {
#  listen     localhost:143;
#  protocol   imap;
#  proxy      on;
# }
#}`
```

Part of nginx/site-enabled/file

```html
`server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/forums.example.net;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name forums.example.net;

    # nginx configuration
 error_page 404 /404.php;

 # rewrite
 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
 }

 # Git folder vulnerability
 location /.git {
  deny all;
  return 403;
 }

 location /controller {
  deny all;
  return 403;
 }
 location /docker_resources {
  deny all;
  return 403;
 }
 location /library {
  deny all;
  return 403;
 }
 location /service {
  deny all;
  return 403;
 }
 location /view {
  deny all;
  return 403;
 }
 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 #
 location ~ /\.ht {
  deny all;
  return 403;
 }
  location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
 }
}`
```